# PlatformException(ERROR, Failed to get location., null) in Flutter location: ^1.4.1

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, flutter-dependencies

I am getting

> PlatformException(ERROR, Failed to get location., null)

while fetching location from device using flutter, location: ^1.4.1. Can anyone help?

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _getLocation();
    return Container();
  }

  Future<Map<String, double>> _getLocation() async {
    var location = new Location();
    try {
      var _permission = await location.hasPermission();
      print(_permission);
      var currentlocation = await location.getLocation();
      print(currentlocation["latitude"]);
      return currentlocation;
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Stacktrace -

```
I/flutter (28694): true
I/flutter (28694): PlatformException(ERROR, Failed to get location., null)
```

Comment: I have the same problem ,I have a collection with set of document , and each document has a filed type Geopoint and  I want to translate some of the latitude , longitude to address , some of them work fine, but other don't work and give me this exception **PlatformException(failed, Failed, null)** , I don't know why .. did you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

So you pulled that package in via `flutter pub get` ...
Did you also rebuild the entire project?
Might be because it did not build the native side of the plugin.

`Stop and Re-Run` might help.